# Cast from Object to List<String>: CastClassException

Tags: java, android, json, ektorp, touchdb

I'm using a TouchDB with ektorp in an Android app to access a CouchDB

The json document I'm accessing has a array of categories:

categories: ['cat1', 'cat2']

In a view query i'm trying to access this array but I get a ClassCastException when trying to convert the result Object to a List:

```
 public void map(Map<String, Object> document, TDViewMapEmitBlock emitter) {
           Object dateAdded = document.get("dateAdded");
           Object expiryDate = document.get("expiryDate");
           boolean expired = false;
             if(expiryDate!=null){
                 expired = CompareDate.isItemExpired(expiryDate);
             }
           List<String> test = (List<String>)document.get("categories");
```

The `.get()` method works fine for single json fields. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `document.get("categories")` returns a `List<String>`? Have you tried to inspect it?

Comment: .get() only returns an object, that's why I was trying to cast it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document is declared as `Map<String, Object>`

So when you do `.get()` - it will return an Object.

There's no direct mapping to `(List<String>)` so this exception is saying you need to cast it to an object rather than a list.

You could change the Map to hold a list of Strings in its values, this would then stop the class cast exception but you should probably review why the Map is declared in the way it is.

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing the Map definition but ended up with lots of errors I didn't understand. I decided to stick with a object and treat it as a string in the end.

Answer (score 2):

The ClassCastException tells you the actual type of the object returned by `document.get("categories");` so you can tell what you are able to cast it to.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be trying to cast the string array to a list of Strings leading to ClassCastException. Rather you should try put the elements of array in list using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

From docs, ClassCastException means:

```
Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.
```

Since, in your case, document.get returns general type Object and you try to cast it to List, you get this exception.